# Validar JTextField para aceptar solamente números

Tags: java, java-swing

Tengo el siguiente codigo, quisiera poder validar que en mi JTextField solo puedan ser introducidos valores numericos.

```
@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object ob =e.getSource();
        String Nombre_Empreado="";
        String Numero_Caja="";
        String Numero_Codigo="";
        String Nombre_Producto="";
        String Precio="";
        String Cantidad="";
        String Total ="";

        String id="";
        String Descripcion="";
        String Precio_Venta="";
        String Cantidad_Proveedor="";
        String Proveedor_Venta="";

             if (ob==Guardar)
            {
                 if (TXT_id.getText().isEmpty()||TXT_descripcion.getText().isEmpty()||TXT_precioventa.getText().isEmpty())
                {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Puede Dejar Valores Nulos");
                }
                else
                {    
                id=TXT_id.getText();
                Descripcion=TXT_descripcion.getText();
                Precio_Venta=TXT_precioventa.getText();
                Cantidad_Proveedor=TXT_stock.getText();
                Proveedor_Venta=C_Proveedor.getSelectedItem().toString();
                GuardarInventario(id,Descripcion,Precio_Venta,Cantidad_Proveedor,Proveedor_Venta);
                }
            }



            if (ob ==registrar)
            {
                if(TXTcodigo.getText().isEmpty() || TCantidad.getText().isEmpty()||TXTpreciov.getText().isEmpty() )
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Puede Dejar Valores Nulos");
                }
                else
                {
                    Nombre_Producto=Cproductos.getSelectedItem().toString();        
                    Nombre_Empreado=Cempreado.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    Numero_Caja=Ccaja.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    Numero_Codigo=TXTcodigo.getText();
                    Cantidad=TCantidad.getText();
                    Precio=TXTpreciov.getText();
                    Double cantidad2=Double.parseDouble(Cantidad);
                    Double Precio2=Double.parseDouble(Precio);
                    Double total=cantidad2*Precio2;
                    Total=""+total;
                    GuardarVentas(Nombre_Empreado,Numero_Caja,Numero_Codigo,Nombre_Producto,Cantidad,Precio,Total);
                }   

            }
            if (ob ==Eliminar)
            {
                DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) Tablainventario.getModel(); 
                dtm.removeRow(Tablainventario.getSelectedRow()); 
            }






        }//Final eventos
```

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
    **Con éstas 5 líneas de código podrás validar de que solo acepte caracteres numéricos**


    char c = evt.getKeyChar();
    if(!Character.isDigit(c))
    {
        evt.consume();
    }
```

Comment: no funciona porque tienes una negacion en el if.

Comment: @Cristian Javier Blanco García Para que sea bien recibida la respusta editala y agrega una explicación y también el consejo que te da Elon

Comment: Esta respuesta no es útil porque no permitiría introducir valores negativos además de el problema de condicional ya antes mencionado. Te recomiendo leer [Te he votado negativamente porque tu respuesta es totalmente incorrecta.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2912)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes restringir todos aquellos caracteres que no sean números. Deberías añadir un evento a tu JTextField

```
@Override
    public void processKeyEvent(KeyEvent ev) {
        if (Character.isDigit(ev.getKeyChar())) {
            super.processKeyEvent(ev);
        }
        ev.consume();
        return;
    }
```

De esta forma el método *consume* de la clase *KeyEvent* no permite el ingreso de signos ni letras.

[*Aquí tienes un ejemplo del código*](https://gist.github.com/gysel/4074617)

Comment: tal vez deberías de esclarecerle un poco el `ev.consume()`

Comment: Esta solución tiene el problema de que no permite introducir valores numéricos negativos, te recomiendo leer el artículo [Te he votado negativamente porque tu respuesta es totalmente incorrecta.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2912)

Comment: Solucion totalmente incorrecta? Stock o precios negativos?

Comment: A eso se le llama ofertas

Comment: No veo ningún campo oferta, y en ese caso con un campo "descuento" el cual indique un porcentaje positivo que representa, como su nombre lo indica, un descuento es suficiente. Saludos